# TableViewer cell editor not working - SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I am trying  to implement an editable table viewer in Eclipse SWT. I think I've done everything ok until now, problem is the table is not editable - nothing happens if I click on any row.

I have registered some CellEditors with all my columns:

```
CellEditor[] editors = new CellEditor[columnNames.length]; 
editors[0] = new TextCellEditor(table);
//do the above for all columns
tableViewer.setCellEditors(editors);
```

and then I specify a cell modifier for my table:

```
tableViewer.setCellModifier(new CellModifier(this));
```

The CellModifier class looks like this:

```
public class CellModifier implements ICellModifier{

private DBStructureView dbView;

public CellModifier(DBStructureView view){
    super();
    this.dbView = view;
}

@Override
public boolean canModify(Object element, String property) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object getValue(Object element, String property) {
    int columnIndex = dbView.getColumnNames().indexOf(property);

    Object result = null;
    AttributeNode node = (AttributeNode) element;

    switch(columnIndex){
    case 0://row id
            result = node.getRow();
    case 1://name
            result = node.getName();
    case 2://value
            result = node.getValue();
    default:
            result = "unknown";
    }

    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}

@Override
public void modify(Object element, String property, Object value) {
    int columnIndex = dbView.getColumnNames().indexOf(property);

    TableItem item = (TableItem) element;
    AttributeNode node = (AttributeNode)item.getData();
    String valueString;

    switch(columnIndex){
    case 0:
        valueString = ((String) value).trim();
        node.setRow(valueString);
        break;
    case 1: 
        valueString = ((String) value).trim();
        node.setName(valueString);
        break;
    case 2:
        valueString = ((String) value).trim();
        node.setValue(valueString);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }   

}
}
```

Having done all this, what can go wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doesn't look like plain SWT, do you use JFace..? I had implemented once cell editor on plain table and it absolutely different code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the bug, it seems I forgot to set the properties for the columns. I added:

```
tableViewer.setColumnProperties(columnNames);
```

and now it works fine, I can edit any of my cells!

Comment: Thanks for this tip! I had ignored this and wasted quite a lot of itme debugging this!

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement in your getValue() misses the `break;` in each case, it always sets result to "unknown".

Then, if I compare your code with the [example](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet009CellEditors.java?revision=1.1&view=co) in [JFace Snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets#Snippet009CellEditors), it seems you are missing

```
tableViewer.update(.);
```

in modify().

But both issues don't explain why "nothing happens", when you click the cell. Since we don't have a running snippet from you, we can only speculate. Did you debug? When you set breakpoints in getValue() and modify(), and click a cell, do you hit the breakpoints?

**Update:** Since you write, that your code doesn't get hit at all, the issue is most probably in the code you haven't shown us.

Please read the Javadoc of [ColumnViewer.setCellEditor()](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ColumnViewer.html#setCellEditors%28org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CellEditor%5B%5D%29):

> Users setting up an editable
>   TreeViewer or TableViewer with more
>   than 1 column have to pass the
>   SWT.FULL_SELECTION style bit

Check if your Table has that style bit.

Comment: Yes, I set the breakpoint in both getValue and modify and they were not called when clicking the cells. You are right about the break; in the switch, I added them later.